# How can I get block data with all transactions with one Solana API request?

Tags: jsonrpc-api, python, api

How can I get the last block or slot with all transactions in it with one Solana API request? The way I found: getSlot() -> getBlock(slotNumber). The problem with this method is that it is very slow. To get full information about a block you need to make 2 requests, it takes 1 or more seconds, and I need to process every new block in the network that comes out once every 0.4 sec. How can I get information about a new block with one request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to process every block as it comes in, the better option is to use the subscription API `blockSubscribe` https://docs.solana.com/api/websocket#blocksubscribe

Otherwise, rather than constantly calling `getSlot` first, you can get a whole range using `getBlocks` https://docs.solana.com/api/http#getblocks or `getBlocksWithLimit` https://docs.solana.com/api/http#getblockswithlimit in the beginning, and then keep incrementing the slot by 1 and calling `getBlock` as you were doing before. Some slots will be empty, and that's normal.